# Timing a method using @Timed annotation - in relation to the input size

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphite, micrometer

Using the `@Timed` annotation we can time how long it takes for a method to run:

```
@Timed 
public void loopInput(int counter){
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        i++;
    }
}
```

But, let's say our method has some input that its size can alter dramatically the time it takes to run the method (like in the example above).

Isn't this time measuring given by `@Timed` is meaningless without some additional potential information about the input size?

It will also be meaningless in case of different output size:

```
    @Timed
    public void printStudentCourses(int studentId){
       //get student from DB
       // ...
       for (Course cource: Student.getCourses()) {
          System.out.println(cource);
       }
    }
```

Of course, it will take longer to print students with a larger course list.

So:

1. What are the real insights we can get from the `@Timed` measurement?
2. Is there a way to add some additional info for the `@Timed` measurement?

Answer (score 2):

`@Timed` is meant to be a simple way to add a timer. That can be useful to get a feel for how long a method is taking, and making you question why it is taking longer than expected.  That data alone would inform you that there might be outliers and a need to measure those separately.

To get the separate insight, adding tags that can help delineate between differing timers can be worthwhile.

Here I'm adding a tag based on how many are being iterated over (buckets might be 1, 2-5, >5)

```
public void printStudentCourses(int studentId){
   //get student from DB
   // ...
   Metrics.timer("my.timer", Tags.of("bucket", chooseBucket(student.getCourses().size()))).record(() -> {
     for (Course course: student.getCourses()) { 
        //Assuming there is something more expensive worth measuring here
        System.out.println(course);
     }
   })
}
```

Comment: So it seems like the @Timed on its own doesn't provide enough information. We need to collect more information in order to get real insights from it. Isn't it true?

Comment: not necessarily. tags can be injected in the code but can also be added externally. for example Prometheus adds the "instance-id", "job" and other other 'static' info. for things that are changed per transaction, you will have to use your own timer (not with @Timed)

Answer (score 0):

the usage of `@Timer` vary with different applications. I personally use it to measure the running time of servlet requests. So in this case you get a high level view of the running time for each request and you can create interesting graphs which gives you insight of how your application works and in case something goes wrong you can create alerts (with the use of other metric collection tools like Prometheus). So to answer your questions:

1. You can measure the time of the function over time (doesn't care about the input size), create histogram, monitor application health
2. one solution would be to add customized tags (like what @checketts mentioned in the answer) or you can create your own logic if it is too complicated to be fit in an existing library.You can export your own metrics with whatever logic you feel comfortable